# How to cleanly format multiple if statements in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

This script works:

```
IF EXIST %PublishRoot%\ConnectionStrings.json IF EXIST %PublishRoot%\Settings.json IF EXIST %PublishRoot%\Web.config (
    call DeployInit %1
    exit /b
)
```

But it's not readable. I tried:

```
IF EXIST %PublishRoot%\ConnectionStrings.json 
IF EXIST %PublishRoot%\Settings.json 
IF EXIST %PublishRoot%\Web.config (
    call DeployInit %1
    exit /b
)
```

But it doesn't work:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

How can I make it more readable?

Answer (score 4):

Use `^` to join multiple lines in Cmd batch files:

```
if this ^
if that ^
do_something
```

Comment: Very clean. Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh, nice approach. I was thinking of using if this goto a, if that goto a, goto :end :a approach